# Build Order Classifier for RTS Games

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I have no experience or knowledge on machine learning. I want to build a system for classifying RTS game replays by their build orders. Build order is a set of tasks (constructing buildings, training soldiers, workers) in a timely basis. A replay consists of the timings of all the tasks done by the two players. There are standard build orders usually players are following which defines the strategy of the games.

So, the problem is to label/classify replays based on their build orders. Since every replay is a unique game, it is not easy to identify build orders by the timings or order of tasks. Here you can see a standard build order defined here http://lotv.spawningtool.com/build/52587/ for a Starcraft 2 game. It is not possible to match the timings or order of the builds or unit counts since they are different in every game and the build orders are evolving and new build orders are created by the time.
To solve this problem, I believe building a machine learning system is necessary.

The question is what should be the easy and simple way to approach this problem? I wonder if neural networks are good for such classifications? or any other concept that is more relevant to such problem?

Comment: I have learnt a lot since that post and have also reread the your post.  Yes, you could use a clustering algorithm or a neural net to label or classify replays based on build order.  The easiest would be to start with an auto clustering algorithm if you don't have labels.  If you do already have labels, try a neural net.  If you want to include the whole sequence of events, then something like a recurrent neural net would allow you to scan the whole sequence and output a label.

Comment: Thanks, I have the labels already, probably, I should use recurrent neural net. as it was suggested me elsewhere.

Comment: another option that is possibly faster and will pick out micro structure is a convolution over your data set, then a max pool.  See here http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/.  I've used this for text classification myself on variable length text.